# Trying to force:source:deploy to a non-Scratch org - "No org configuration found for name"

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx

Now I want to source:force:deploy to a Developer org (not a scratch org)

I do:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u mydevorg.user@xx.com
```

... and I get the error below.  What am I missing here?

```
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  No org configuration found for name mydevorg.user@xx.com
```

Comment: NVM - I had a typo in the username :-/

Answer (score 2):

I had a typo in the username :-/

Comment: Happens to the best of us! FYI, you can set a default user name or alias to make typos less likely in the future (force:config:set defaultusername=yourusername and force:alias:set myorgalias=yourusername).

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning what you want to deploy. Before this you need to login to target org:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com -a alias
```

deploy command to dev org is as below:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p src/lwc/anySingleComponent -u alias
```

if you mention -s in login, like below:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com -a alias -s
```

this user name becomes your default.
By using below it directly deploys to your default org

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p src/lwc/anySingleComponent
```

If you want to deploy classes or lwc or aura full folder

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p src/lwc
sfdx force:source:deploy -p src/classes
sfdx force:source:deploy -p src/aura
```